# How to remove margin from sides of ion slide?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, ionic-framework, ionic5

I have added ionic slider in my app problem is from right side it is having margin i want to remove that marging how i cound do this

[image]

```
<template>
  <IonPage>
    <ion-content class="background">
      <div id="product_background">
        <Topbar />
        <div class="container">
          <ion-text color class="top-left">
            <h1>ARTICS PRO</h1>
          </ion-text>
          <ion-text color class="heart_icon">
            <ion-icon :icon="heartOutline"></ion-icon>
            <ion-icon :icon="shareSocial"></ion-icon>
          </ion-text>

          <ion-text color class="top-left2">
            <p>Steelseries</p>
          </ion-text>
          <ion-text class="slides_count">
            <p>{{activeSlide}} / 3</p>
          </ion-text>
          <ion-text color class="bottom-right">
            <p>ARTICS 7</p>
          </ion-text>

          <ion-text color class="bottom-right2">
            <p>Steelseries</p>
          </ion-text>

          <!--  -->
          <ion-slides pager="true" :options="slideOpts" @ionSlideDidChange="ionSlideDidChange">
            <ion-slide>
              <img :src="require('@/assets/headset_mockup.png')" style="height:105vw;width:500vw" />
            </ion-slide>
            <ion-slide>
              <img :src="require('@/assets/headset_mockup.png')" style="height:105vw;width:100vw" />
            </ion-slide>
            <ion-slide>
              <img :src="require('@/assets/headset_mockup.png')" style="height:105vw;width:100vw" />
            </ion-slide>
          </ion-slides>
        </div>

        <div id="product_price">
          <svg width="20" height="15" style="margin-right:5px">
            <rect
              width="20"
              height="15"
              style="fill:#ffff;stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(255, 255, 255);"
            />
          </svg>
          <svg width="20" height="15" style="margin-right:5px">
            <rect width="20" height="15" style="fill:#000000;stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
          </svg>
          <svg width="20" height="15" style="margin-right:5px">
            <rect
              width="20"
              height="15"
              style="fill:#808080;stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(128,128,128)"
            />
          </svg>
          <svg width="20" height="15" style="margin-right:5px">
            <rect width="20" height="15" style="fill:#FF0000 ;stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(255,0,0)" />
          </svg>
          <svg width="20" height="15" style="margin-right:5px">
            <rect
              width="20"
              height="15"
              style="fill:#FFFF00 ;stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(255,255,0)"
            />
          </svg>
          <h2>$3,9000</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="product_info">
        <p>Product Information</p>
      </div>
      <div id="cart_icon">
        <ion-button>
          <ion-icon :icon="cart"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
  </IonPage>
</template>

<script >
import {
  IonContent,
  IonPage,
  IonText,
  IonIcon,
  IonSlides,
  IonSlide,
  IonButton,
} from "@ionic/vue";
import Topbar from "../Resources/Topbar.vue";
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";
import { heartOutline, shareSocial, cart } from "ionicons/icons";
export default {
  name: "Index",
  components: {
    IonContent,
    IonPage,
    Topbar,
    IonText,
    IonIcon,
    IonSlides,
    IonSlide,
    IonButton,
  },
  setup() {
    return {
      router: useRouter(),
      heartOutline,
      shareSocial,
      cart,
    };
  },
  data() {
    return {
      activeSlide: 1,
      length: 3,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    ionSlideDidChange: async function (e) {
      this.activeSlide = (await e.target.getActiveIndex()) + 1;
      // e.target.getActiveIndex().then(i => {
      //   this.activeIndex = i;

      // });
    },
  },
};
</script>
<style scoped>
ion-slide {
  width: 100% !important;
}

.swiper-wrapper {
  width: min-content !important;
}
ion-button {
  --background: #280c4c;
}
.background {
  --background: url("../../assets/product_background.png") 0 0/100% 100%
      no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(to bottom, #1a1240 35%, #6528af 70%, #736eed 100%);
}
#product_background {
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 20px;
}

.bottom-right {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 14px;
  right: 16px;
}
.bottom-right2 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 16px;
}
#product_info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 16px;
  color: white;
}
#cart_icon {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 50px;
  font-size: 30vw;
  color: white;
}
#product_price {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 70px;
  left: 20px;
  color: white;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin: -20px;
}
.heart_icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 180px;
  left: 8px;
}
.top-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  left: 8px;
}
.top-left2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  left: 6px;
}
.slides_count {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 40px;
  right: 16px;
}
</style>
```

I tried to override existing tags sizes but they behave differently. I want to do it as it should not be changes in different kind of devices. should be adjust according sceen size

Answer (score 0):

With the magic of CSS.

```
ion-slide {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Just be careful to check it is in fact a margin and not padding as Ionic uses padding quite a lot for a native look.

Alternatively, you can add pre-packaged Ionic CSS for no margins or padding.

```
<ion-slide class="ion-no-padding ion-no-margin">
</ion-slide>
```

Also, you should really avoid using inline CSS with `style` tags if you can. Add them in to [classes](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp) in CSS instead. It's easier to manage in the long run.

Comment: It is not effected ..still margin is there

Comment: Is the margin on the slides element or the slide?

Comment: Sometimes you'll need to use !important with the css parameters to override.

Comment: half of marging because of slide other half is because of element